# destructive/stress testing test cases for Waze-like/location based mobile app

Tags: mobile, stress-testing, mobile-applications

can i get suggestions regarding testing of location based Waze-like mobile apps

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use test techniques such Scenario Testing, Domain Testing and Combination Testing, you can design different kind of tests for each feature in the app, in order to have good test coverage.

If you not, a good intro would be BBST resources:

Video - http://testingeducation.org/BBST/testdesign/

Book - [https://www.amazon.com/Test-Design-Workbook-Cem-Kaner/dp/0989811964](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0989811964)